# Failure to render static files django with no visible error

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, django

when i run runserver and try to load my css files as well as the html all i get is a white page nothing comes up, html only appears when i remove static links to leave it as bare html . I'm running the project in development mode

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

  <!--Templates CSS-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,500,600,700&amp;amp;subset=latin-ext"
    rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/Linearicons/Linearicons/Font/demo-files/demo.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static  'plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/owl-carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/slick/slick/slick.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/nouislider/nouislider.min.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/lightGallery-master/dist/css/lightgallery.min.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/jquery-bar-rating/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />

</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please
        <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
      </p>
    <![endif]-->
  {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
</body>

<!--Templates JS-->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/nouislider/nouislider.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/popper.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/masonry.pkgd.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery.matchHeight-min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/slick/slick/slick.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery-bar-rating/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/slick-animation.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/lightGallery-master/dist/js/lightgallery-all.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/sticky-sidebar/dist/sticky-sidebar.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js' %} "></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/gmap3.min.js' %}"></script>

</html>
```

development server shows me files are being retrieved

```
July 06, 2020 - 22:45:25
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'zershecom.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 90726
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 29063
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/fonts/Linearicons/Linearicons/Font/demo-files/demo.css HTTP/1.1" 200 52360
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/owl-carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1013
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/slick/slick/slick.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1729
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 159515
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/nouislider/nouislider.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5121
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3351
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/lightGallery-master/dist/css/lightgallery.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 20458
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/jquery-bar-rating/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css HTTP/1.1" 200 958
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:05] "GET /static/plugins/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 15180
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:06] "GET /static/css/autopart.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6238
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:06] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 312058
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:07] "GET /static/plugins/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 19033
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:07] "GET /static/plugins/nouislider/nouislider.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 23500
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:07] "GET /static/plugins/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5594
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:07] "GET /static/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 44342
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:08] "GET /static/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 60010
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:08] "GET /static/plugins/jquery.matchHeight-min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3380
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:08] "GET /static/plugins/masonry.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 25250
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:09] "GET /static/plugins/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 89493
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:09] "GET /static/plugins/slick/slick/slick.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 41953
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:09] "GET /static/plugins/isotope.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 34713
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:09] "GET /static/plugins/jquery-bar-rating/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5826
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:09] "GET /static/plugins/slick-animation.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1774
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:10] "GET /static/plugins/sticky-sidebar/dist/sticky-sidebar.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 11896
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:10] "GET /static/plugins/gmap3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9819
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:10] "GET /static/plugins/lightGallery-master/dist/js/lightgallery-all.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 49547
[06/Jul/2020 22:46:10] "GET /static/plugins/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 76272
```

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FILE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

replace your static paths with this and try